# Spring + SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message

Tags: spring, spring-ws, wss4j

I have a spring web application with jsp pages that calls different web services and displays the results in a jsp page. The spring web application has username/login spring security attached to it.

I am adding a call to a web service that handles security. For the WebServiceGateway, I added a security interceptor. (See below)

```
<bean id="securityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken Timestamp" />
    <property name="securementUsername" value="Bert" />
    <property name="securementPassword" value="Ernie" />
    <property name="timestampPrecisionInMilliseconds" value="true" />
</bean>
```

When I added the wss4j into my pom file, I now get the following error on the web service side:

```
[28-13:46:26]DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(): Could not complete request [http-8080-2]
org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:163)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:172)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.Saaj13Implementation.writeTo(Saaj13Implementation.java:268)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:159)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to get header stream in saveChanges: 
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1101)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes(MessageImpl.java:945)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1096)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be a bit too late, but you seem to be suffering from what is described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/faq.html#java-1.6). The Xerces implementation in Java 6 is apparently not compatible with Spring Web Services.
Their solution is to start messing with endorsed libs, but this is something I would like to avoid. I have not yet found a good solution that does not involve modifying the JVM installation.

Arjen Poutsma seems to have another solution. He removed all the Xerces and Xalan dependencies. Then it works. Unless you need features from Xerces/Xalan in some other part of you web service application you could try this. The relevant ticket is [SWS-175](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-175).

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I tried putting the Xerces and Xalan jars in the Tomcat endorsed folder. But it just keep asking that I'm missing another jar. Forget it. What I did is delete the Xerces and Xalan (same with what Arjen did). And it worked!

Comment: @Christ so you just exclude it?

Answer (score 0):

I got exact same issue wherein spring client of soap web service was working absolutely fine when tested on tomcat and was giving following exception when tested on jboss:

`org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message`

With the answer given above, I changed jboss-deployment-structure file as follows and added activation, xerces and xalan in exclusion:

```
<exclusions>
     <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
     <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
     <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
     <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
     <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
     <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
     <module name="org.slf4j" />
     <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
     <module name="javaee.api"/> 
     <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
     <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
     <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
     <module name="javax.activation.api"/>
</exclusions>
```

This resolved the issue on jboss.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem today. Tried all the possible ways and finally removed Xalan.jar and xerces.jar. In fact not only Xalan and Xerces JARS but XercesImpl.jar and all versions of Xalan JARS as well.

Now it's working completely fine.