# SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap-client

I am using Java 8 with SpringBoot 2.7.0.  I have some WSDL files that I use to generate some code using the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin. I then create a SOAP client to try invoke the SOAP services:

**SOAP Client**

```
public List<SupplierInfo> getAvailableSuppliers() {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    GetAvailableSuppliersRequest req = new GetAvailableSuppliersRequest();
    JAXBElement<GetAvailableSuppliersRequest> request = factory.createGetAvailableSuppliersRequest(req);
    GetAvailableSuppliersResponse response = (GetAvailableSuppliersResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    return response.getSupplierInfo();
}
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class AvailabilitySOAPClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        //marshaller.setContextPath("com.mycompany.restosgi.soap.generated");
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.restosgi.soap.generated", "com.mycompany.transit._2008a.availability");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public AvailabilitySOAPClient availabilitySOAPClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AvailabilitySOAPClient client = new AvailabilitySOAPClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8080/ws");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

When I call the SOAP client, I get the following error:

> Error    DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon8-dom.jar is
> on the classpath
>
> SAAJ0539: Unable to get header stream in saveChanges
>
> SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
>
> org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException: Could not
> write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart
> message; nested exception is
> com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during
> saving a multipart message

Comment: please refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018385/com-sun-xml-internal-messaging-saaj-soapexceptionimpl-error-during-saving-a-mul to resolve your issue , it might provide you some insights.

Comment: @vanshikamalhotra, thank you for your reply.  I did read that post earlier, it suggests using Axiom or upgrading Xalan.  I have tried adding `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom.wso2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axiom</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.11-wso4v12</version>
</dependency>` or `<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>` to  my maven dependencies.  But this does not help.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have  also tried adding the following maven dependencies too:   `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my pom, fixed my issue.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/saxon-dom -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
    <version>8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What does it exactly do?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error in springboot 3.

Excluding below dependencies helped me.

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```